# Get state of SFX (spec. time) in XNA using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, xna

I have a specific problem that might have a different solution than the one I'm thinking of (and included in the title). It is as follows:

My character revs up a chainsaw by pressing a button, keeps it going for as long as the player presses the button, and then revs down when the player releases the button. Now I want to add SFX to this. How can I smoothly go from SFX to SFX in order (revup, loop, revdown). Can I somehow check the SFX for timing, so that I wont end up with a gap between them. If I check 
SFX.State = SoundState.Playing,
I might end up having a gap between the next being played. Alternatively, can I start/resume a SFX at a different time than it's real starting time? So that I can have revup/loop/revdown in the same SFX and just control what time of it plays.

Thanks for any insight into this!

/Christian

Answer (score 0):

For the revup to loop part, you know the exact length of revup, so you can just time the start of loop using gameTime. For the revdown part, that's easy, when the button release is detected, simply stop revup or loop, whichever was playing and start revdown on the same frame.

Comment: Thank's for the answer. Ok, I'll try it out and see if I notice any inconsistencies. I'll get back to you once done!